# how WebGL return pixel color when blending is disabled?

Tags: webgl

when there is no blending, what is the function that give color pixel from fragment color and clearColor ?

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("#normal");
const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl',  {premultipliedAlpha: false});

gl.clearColor(0 , 0.5 , 0.7 , 0.65);
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    lime, /*  lime=( 0.0 , 1.0 , 0.0 , 1.0 ) */
    lime 10px,
    orange 10px,  /* orange=( 1.0 , 0.64705.. , 0.0 , 1.0) */
    orange 20px
  );
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="128" height="128" id="normal"></canvas>
```

[image: snapshot and color get from Gimp]

**body**        `1.0 , 0.647 , 0.0 , 1.0`
**canvas** `0.0 , 0.5 , 0.7 , 0.65`
**(1)canvas x alpha** `0.0 , 0.325 , 0.455 , 0.4225` 
**(2)body x (1-alpha)** `0.35 , 0.2264 , 0.0 , 0.35` 
**(1)+(2)=** `0.35 , 0.5514 , 0.455 , 0.7725`

So, the result is like :

> gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
> gl.blendFunc(gl.SRC_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

but i did not write that code...

16/07/2021 : Merci peabrainiac !

the result is the same as with :
gl.blendFuncSeparate(gl.SRC_AlPHA,gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,gl.ONE,gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

color(RGB) = sourceColor * As + destinationColor * (1-As)

color(A) = sourceAlpha + destinationAlpha * ( 1-As)

color(RGB) = (0.0, 0.5 , 0.7) * 0.65 + (1.0 , 0.647.. , 0.0) * 0.35

color(A) = 0.65 + 1.0 * 0.35

color(RGB) = (0.35 , 0.55147.. , 0.455)

color(A) = 1.0

test :

```js
test('#normal');
test3('#blendfunc');

function test(selector) {
  const canvas = document.querySelector(selector);
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  
  var r = 0;
  var g = 0.5;
  var b = 0.7;
  var a = 0.65;
  
  gl.clearColor(r * a, g * a, b * a, a);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
}

function test3(selector) {
  const canvas = document.querySelector(selector);
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  
  const vs=`
    void main() {
      gl_Position=vec4(0,0,0,1);
      gl_PointSize = 128.;
    }
  `;
  const fs=`
    precision highp float;
    
    void main() {
    float r=0.0;
    float g=0.5;
    float b=0.7;
    float a=0.65;

      gl_FragColor=vec4(r*a,g*a,b*a,a);
      
      // it works with gl_FragColor = vec4 (r, g, b, a)
      //However I am not in {premultipliedAlpha: false}
      //gl_FragColor=vec4(r,g,b,a);

    }
  `;
  
  const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vs);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  
  const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fs);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  
  gl.useProgram(program);
  
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  //gl.blendFunc(gl.ONE, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  gl.blendFuncSeparate(gl.SRC_ALPHA,gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,gl.ONE,gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  
  gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS,0,1);
  
  
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    lime,
    lime 10px,
    orange 10px, /* 1,0.647,1,0 */
    orange 20px
  );
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="128" height="128" id="normal"></canvas>
<canvas width="128" height="128" id="blendfunc"></canvas>
```

...oups it does not work !

```js
test('#normal');
test3('#blendfunc');

function test(selector) {
  const canvas = document.querySelector(selector);
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  
  var r = 0;
  var g = 0.5;
  var b = 0.7;
  var a = 0.65;
  
  gl.clearColor(r * a, g * a, b * a, a);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT); 
}

function test3(selector) {
  const canvas = document.querySelector(selector);
  const gl = canvas.getContext('webgl');
  
  const vs=`
    void main() {
      gl_Position=vec4(0,0,0,1);
      gl_PointSize = 128.;
    }
  `;
  const fs=`
    precision highp float;
    
    void main() {
    float r=0.0;
    float g=0.5;
    float b=0.7;
    float a=0.65;
    
    gl_FragColor=vec4(r,g,b,a);

    }
  `;
  
  const vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader, vs);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  
  const fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader, fs);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  
  const program = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(program, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(program, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(program);
  
  gl.useProgram(program);
  
  gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
  gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
  
  gl.enable(gl.BLEND);
  
  gl.blendFuncSeparate(gl.SRC_ALPHA,gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,gl.ONE,gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
  
  gl.viewport(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

  gl.drawArrays(gl.POINTS,0,1);
  
  
}
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    45deg,
    lime,
    lime 10px,
    orange 10px, /* 1,0.647,1,0 */
    orange 20px
  );
}
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas width="128" height="128" id="normal"></canvas>
<canvas width="128" height="128" id="blendfunc"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case blending is not happening inside of WebGL but inside the browser, just like with any other image with a color of `0 , 0.5 , 0.7 , 0.65`.

Blending in WebGL simply changes how the values emitted from a fragment shader get blended with the values already in that buffer. When blending is disabled, as it is by default, they simply [overwrite the old values](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending#Blend_enabling) without any sort of blending. Similarly, `glClear` always just overwrites the old values [even if blending is enabled](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml#description).

So, in your case the main buffer / canvas is indeed completely filled with the rgba values `0, 0.5, 0.7, 0.65`, not blended with anything else in any way; however, as with any partially transparent element, this is then [blended linearly](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#alpha) with the background by the browser.

Comment: what does "blended linearly" mean ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, [this part of the spec here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#alpha) specifies that blending elements with the background should always happen with the interpolation method specified [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/compositing-1/#simplealphacompositing), which is indeed the same as `gl.blendFuncSeparate(gl.SRC_ALPHA,gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA,gl.ONE,gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)` would be in WebGL.